# MongoDB configuration with Spring Boot?

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot

I am using `ReactiveMongo` in the `Spring Boot` configured project.

## service

```
@Document(collection = "tbl_created_service")
public class Services {
 @Id
 private ObjectId objectId;
 private Long id;
  // Getters and setters
}
```

## ServiceReactiveRepository

```
public interface ServiceReactiveRepository extends ReactiveMongoRepository<Services, String> 
{
}
```

## ServiceService

```
public interface ServicesService {
   Long addNewService(Services services);
}
```

## ServiceImpl

```
@Service
public class ServicesServiceImpl implements ServicesService {

  @Autowired
  ServiceReactiveRepository serviceReactiveRepository;

  @Override
  public Long addNewService(Services servicesTypeDto)  {
     serviceReactiveRepository.save(servicesTypeDto);
     return null;
  }
```

## application.yml

```
  spring:
  profiles:
    active: dev
---
spring:
  profiles: dev
  data.mongodb:
    host: 127.0.0.1
    port: 27017
    database: dev

---
```

## MainApllication class

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class PartnersApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(PartnersApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

When I am hitting the endpoint, I can see the data is binding and coming to `ServicesServiceImpl.addNewService()` but somehow it's not creating a new collection in DB (If not exists) i.e. `tbl_created_service`

However, If I add the collection manually and hit the service, Then it's creating a new document in `"tbl_created_service"`.

Is the right way to do it? or I am missing something?

Any hint would be appreciable :)

Comment: Services ID field is ObjectId and not String, right? In ServiceReactiveRepository is String.

Comment: Missed it, Replaced with `objectId` but it's still the same.

Answer (score 1):

just put this at your application.properties
spring.data.mongodb.uri=URIconnection

this will work when you will use an MongoDb atlas. Just create cluster and connect get the Java URI link then put it in your property. When you run your application it will auto generate the collections declared at your Entity class.

Comment: This answer saved me from over 1hour of stressing over same issue. Thanks man